# Do C getopt and getopt_long only work for main arguments?

Tags: c, getopt, getopt-long

the question is pretty clear, I wonder because the man says

> The  getopt() function parses the command-line arguments.

And I am trying to use it with another function which has the same signature as the main and the `argc` and `argv` are obtained with `wordexp` so everythings seems the same, but when calling getopt I get a segmentation fault immediately after calling getopt_long.

```
#define   OPT_HELP    'h'
#define   OPTL_HELP   "help"
#define   OPT_MESS    'm'
#define   OPTL_MESS   "message"

#define   OPT_STRING  "hm:"

struct option longopts[] = {
  {OPTL_HELP,     no_argument, 0, OPT_HELP},
  {OPTL_MESS,     required_argument, 0, OPT_MESS},
  {0, 0, 0, 0}
};

#define FLAG_MESS 1

void cmd_chat(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int c, indexptr;
  short flag = 0;
  char message[481];
  while ((c = getopt_long(argc, argv, OPT_STRING,
          longopts, &indexptr)) != -1) {
    debug(MAGENTA "cmd_chat", MAGENTA "c value: %d", c);
    switch (c) {
      case OPT_HELP:
        debug(MAGENTA "cmd_chat", MAGENTA "calling help");
        help(argv[0]);
        return;
        break;
      case OPT_MESS:
        flag |= FLAG_MESS;
        strncpy(message, optarg, 481);
        break;
      default:
        usage(argv[0]);
        break;
    }
  }


[...]
```

It might be that, but if so I wonder why it is like that also why we should pass the `argc` and `argv` to `getopt`(`_long`).

Thank you.

Comment: The one assumption that isn't often stated is that you call `getopt()` et al consistently with the same values for `argc` and `argv`, rather than changing the list on each call.  If you use `getopt()` to process command line arguments, and then subsequently use it to access some other set of arguments, you could — not necessarily will — run into problems.  Are you doing anything like that?  (Basically, there's no provision for concurrency — it isn't thread-safe — and there's no provision for reuse.  There usually is a semi-undocumented way to reset the system so it starts over, but it varies.)

Comment: No calls to `getopt` come from the same thread and so are done sequentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `getopt()` and `getopt_long()` will work with every proper `char **` and `int`, there is no difference between `argv` and any other `char **`. 
If you'll pass `argv` and `argc`, or their copies from main to your function and call `getopt()` from there it will work. Show how your function got `argc` and `argv`;

Comment: Okay cool. I really don't see where that segmentation fault come from...
I have printed `argv` values before a call to the command (it is a shell program) `chat -h`, the argv is well parsed and argc is set to 2. I have tried a simple call to getopt without any `while` loop followed immediately by a print of the returned value, and I still get the segmentation fault. I can see it come from the call to `getopt_long` because the print isn't done.

Comment: So do you call getopt twice in your program? If you call it twice, you need to set `optind` to `0` before second call. And provide mcve: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have commented the while loop and replaced it with a single call to getopt_long and I get the segmentation fault, so without twice calls, but I have tried to set optind to 0 before the first call and it works. I don't see it in the man.